# New window to show selected image from ListView doesn't have an access to image path

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview, mvvm

I have an application with ListView, I add Images to that List by click on Add Image Button, I also have a button to remove Images from that List. I use SelectedImage object for that and everything works just fine. But I would like to have a button to show selected image, and this is how I'm doing this:

```
        private ObservableCollection<Image> imageList = new ObservableCollection<Image>();
        private Image selectedImage = new Image();

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            AddImagesCommand = new RelayCommand(AddImagesMethod);
            RemoveImagesCommand = new RelayCommand(RemoveImagesMethod);
            ShowImageCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowImageMethod);
            SelectedImageCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectedImageMethod);
        }

        public ICommand AddImagesCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ShowImageCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand RemoveImagesCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand SelectedImageCommand { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Image> ImageList
        {
            get
            {
                return imageList;
            }
        }

          public Image SelectedImage
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedImage;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedImage = value;
            }
        }

        public void SelectedImageMethod()
        {
            Image selected = SelectedImage;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedImage");
        }


        public void AddImagesMethod()
        {
            ...
            blablabla
            ....
            imageList.Add(new Image
            {
                Name = _name,
                SafeName = safeImageName,
                Weight = sLen,
                CheckboxDefault = false
            }) ;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ImageList);
        }


        public void RemoveImagesMethod()
        {
            imageList.Remove(SelectedImage);
            RaisePropertyChanged("RemoveImagesCommand");
        }

        public void ShowImageMethod()
        {
            //string V = @"pack://application:,,,/inred;component/Sources/test.jpg";
            //string V = @"pack://application:,,,/inred;component/Sources/" + SelectedImage.SafeName;
            ImageWindow win2 = new ImageWindow(SelectedImage.Name);
            win2.Show();
            RaisePropertyChanged("ShowImageCommand");
        }
```

The problem is that SelectedImage.Name and SelectedImage.SafeName are empty and I don't understand why if the same SelectedImage is used for RemoveImageCommand and works fine. String V with test.jpg works, but the second V doesn't. Please give me some pointers what I'm missing.

**UPDATE:**
Here is XAML of the MainWindow:

```
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
        <ListView x:Name="Images" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="20,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="581" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SafeName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="120">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Weight" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Weight}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header = "Actions" Width = "150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Button Content="Show" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowImageCommand, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Button Content="Annotate" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.AnnotateImageCommand, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header = "Default" Width = "50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton GroupName="allFiles" IsChecked="{Binding CheckboxDefault}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Add Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="645,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.282,-0.25" Command="{Binding AddImagesCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Remove Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="645,226,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.282,-0.25" Command="{Binding RemoveImagesCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
```

And here is the ImageWindow:

```
    public partial class ImageWindow : Window
    {
        public ImageWindow(string imagePath)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(imagePath);
            bitmap.EndInit();
            ImageViewer1.Source = bitmap;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can your share the content of `ImageWindow` amd xaml for binding a commands?

Comment: Also why do you need to call `RaisePropertyChanged` for commands? And don't have it for selected image property

Comment: Also, calling `this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ImageList)` after adding an Image is pointless.

Comment: Having a SelectedImageMethod makes no sense. Just bind the ListView's SelectedItem property to the SelectedImage property of your view model, and fire the PropertyChanged event in the SelectedImage setter.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I just added ```ImageWindow``` code and xaml with bindings.

Comment: @Clemens, you might be right, but it's a matter of optimization, by now I would like to make it work, I'm not sure that removing ```SelectedImageMethod``` would solve my problem.

Comment: The solution to your problem is the SelectedItem Binding to a property with change notification. That's not about optimization, but just *how to do it*.

Comment: Thank you, I did as you said, but it doesn't fix the problem. I still get ArgumentNullException at ```bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(imagePath)```, so I guess imagePath is still empty for some reason.

Comment: But you didn't try to debug your code to find out *why* imagePath is empty? If `SelectedItem` is not null, but `SelectedImage.Name` is null, you have certainly added an Image with a null `Name`.

Comment: As a note, you don't need to call BeginInit and EndInit when you create a BitmapImage from an Uri. There is a constructor which allows `ImageViewer1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));`.

Comment: In MvvM VM should never have reference to a Window! Does your Image window do anything apart from showing an image? i.e. like delete? You could just bind the window to a view model and have a converter in your xaml to transform string to Bitmap. And also setting manually datacontext is not a good sign, why do you need all of those names on controls and all of them are fixed, if you resize the window everything will stay exactly the same.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, I'm newbie at MVVM world, so I just have it this way (controls) because I was like that is some tutorial. ```ImageWindow``` only should display SelectedImage from ListView.

Comment: @Clemens, I'm trying to debug it, and the only strange thing I see it's that after I select image on the list, the program flow goes to the setter and to getter after that. At that point ```SelectedImage.Name``` equals to the path to the selected image, which is perfectly fine. But then again in ```ShowImageMethod``` ```SelectedImage.Name``` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that there is an item selected when you click on the button? Also, since you bind the `CommandParameter` to the current `Image` in the `ListView`, you should use this parameter in your command:

```
ShowImageCommand = new RelayCommand<Image>(ShowImageMethod);
...
public void ShowImageMethod(Image image)
{
    ImageWindow win2 = new ImageWindow(image.Name);
    win2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed, could you maybe send me some link where the difference between ```RelayCommand<Image>(ShowImageMethod)``` and ```RelayCommand(ShowImageMethod)``` is explained? Because I still don't understand why my ```RemoveImageMethod``` works, and when I should use methods with pointed object type and when I don't have to specify it.

Comment: There is a generic `RelayCommand<T>` class that accepts a parameter of type `T`. You pass the value to the `Action<T>` by doing `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` in your XAML.

Comment: Please, I have one last question, If I would like to have a method like ```ShowImageMethod```, but instead of ```<Image>``` I would like to pass 2 arguments (let say ```Image``` and ```Sound```), unfortunately, there is no ``RelayCommand``` constructor with 2 parameters. I'm new at C#, but the solution I'm thinking about comes from C++ - I mean Templates, which I guess can be also implemented in C#, where parameter ```T``` would be a new class consisting 2 fields ```sound``` and ```image``` and set/get,  but maybe there is a more natural and smart way to do this?

Comment: @Lukashou-AGH: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comment field. If you post the link to your new question here, I'll try my best to help you out.

Comment: Thank you anyway, here is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158214/c-sharp-wpf-generic-relaycommandt-with-2-parameters